# Calculator without if/else or switch

Tags: java, calculator

I am trying to write calculator for `+ - * /` without conditions. The operator is stored as a string.

Is there anyway to achieve it?

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ////String Operator = "";
        String L1="";
        String L2="";
        String op = "+";
        double a = 3;
        double b = 2;

        //Operator p = p.
        Operator p;
        b = Operator.count(a, op, b);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public enum Operator {
        PLUS("+"), MINUS("-"), DIVIDE("/"), MULTIPLY("*");

        private final String operator;

        public static double count(double a,String op,double b) {
            double RetVal =0;
            switch (Operator.valueOf(op)) {
            case PLUS:
                RetVal= a + b;
            case MINUS:
                RetVal= a - b;
            case DIVIDE:
                RetVal= a / b;
            case MULTIPLY:
                RetVal= a * b;
            }
            return RetVal;
        }

        Operator(String operator) {
            this.operator = operator;

        }
        // uniwersalna stała grawitacyjna (m3 kg-1 s-2)
    }

}
```

Got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class Main$Operator.+

Any clues?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. Please ask a specific questions and we are happy to help you.

Comment: I would use the built in Javascript interpreter.

Comment: Java's still turing complete without if/else and case/switch, but why would you want to handicap yourself like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a strategy pattern and store a calculation strategy for each operator.

```
interface Calculation {
  double calculate(double op1, double op2);
}

class AddCalculation implements Calculation {
  double calculate(double op1, double op2) {
    return op1 + op2;
  }
}

//others as well

Map<String, Calculation> m = ...;

m.put("+", new AddCalculation());
```

During execution you then get the calculation objects from the map and execute `calculate()`.

Comment: +1 This video contains a very nice example for just this operation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc

Comment: Of course, technically, this is just hiding the conditions, which are in the b-tree search.

Comment: @Software Monkey but you can't expect to do it without *any* conditions hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

i think using an enum would be a nice option:

```
Enum Operation{
PLUS("+")
MINUS("-")
DIVIDE("/")
MULTIPLY("*")
}
```

then you could go with

```
switch(Operation.valueOf(userInputString)){
case PLUS: return a+b;
case MINUS: return a-b;
case DIVIDE: return a/b;
case MULTIPLY: return a*b;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer - but unfortunately the OP did restrict to "no switch".

Comment: In Java 7 you then can skip the enum and directly use `case "+"`.

Comment: weeeeell theoretically, switch is a program counter jump map and not a condition ;P This is also, why stuff like case "+" is pretty ugly, because the compiler (i think) needs to degenerate the switch to a series of if(equal)elseif(equal)elseif(equal) instead of just executing "jmp 4*inputvalue" (so to speak)

Answer (score 0):

how about hashing? Hash the operators as a key-value pair ("+": +). For the string operatory, hash it and grab the value. Experiment with that

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Peter Lawrey, ScriptEngine/JavaScript might be a good choice for this.  Visit this little [JavaScript interpreter applet](http://pscode.org/jse.html) to explore the possibilities.

Comment: And lisp too is wonderful, or python... But that's not the point here. This would not be tagged java otherwise.