# A calculator with no if's

Tags: java

So i wanted to ask if its possible to make a calculator but without if statements like normally i do it like:

```
Scanner userInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Number: ");
double number1 = userInput1.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Operator: ");
String operator = userInput1.next();
System.out.print("Another Number: ");
double number2 = userInput1.nextDouble();
if(operator.equals(+))
{
   double result = number1 + number2;
   System.out.println("The result is " + result);
}
```

And i need to make a if statement and "ask" if the operator equals plus. is it possible to make it that you dont need to to that with the if statements and do it like that:

```
Scanner userInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Number: ");
double number1 = userInput1.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Operator: ");
String operator = userInput1.next();
System.out.print("Another Number: ");
double number2 = userInput1.nextDouble();
System.out.println("The result is " number1 + operator + number2);
```

Now it would just say as example: The result is 15+17 and i wanted to ask if its possible to make it  that it gives me the result without the if statements.
Thanks

Comment: (I am not very sure if that is even right code i just wrote something)

Comment: this question already have answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926155/calculator-without-if-else-or-switch

Comment: if you dont want to use if statements then you can go with switch

Comment: Check out [Switch](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_switch.asp) in Java

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this using no `if`, no `switch`, and no other branching language constructs*. The basic idea is to use a map of functions to do the operations, and then use the operator (as a string) to look up the function in the map.

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

public class Calculator {
    private static final Map<String, BinaryOperator<Integer>> operators;
    static {
        operators = new HashMap<>();
        operators.put("+", (a, b) -> a + b);
        operators.put("-", (a, b) -> a - b);
        operators.put("*", (a, b) -> a * b);
        operators.put("/", (a, b) -> a / b);
    }

    public static int doOperation(int a, int b, String op) {
        return operators.get(op).apply(a, b);
    }
}
```

This is just to demonstrate the concept, so I haven't done any console input/output or parsing, and there is no error-handling. If the string `op` isn't in the map, it will throw a `NullPointerException`; if you like, you can use [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) to handle that case.

<sub>*Yes, of course there *is* branching going on under the hood in order to make `get` and `getByDefault` work. What I mean is that this code itself doesn't use any language constructs that are compiled to conditional jumps.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial model.  It does not have all the necessary error controls for invalid input and it only supports one operator.  But it is a start.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean more = true;
        while (more) {
            int result = 0;
            System.out.print(
                    "Enter two ints separated by spaces");
            int a = input.nextInt();
            int b = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the operator");
            String c = input.next();
            switch (c) {
            case "+":
                System.out.println(a + b);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Unknown operator");
            }
            System.out.print("Another? ");
            String answer = input.next();
            switch (answer.charAt(0)) {
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                more = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```